# Unable to load dynamic php_mbstring.dll library

Tags: php-7, ubuntu-16.04

I am checking for my php version using

> php -v

command in console and I am getting a WARNING below

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mbstring.dll' -
>   /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 PHP
>   7.0.4-7ubuntu2 (cli) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

I have uncommented this line extension=php_mbstring.dll in my /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini file and this doesn't seem to solve my problem. How would i get rid of this warning?

Comment: `php_mbstring.dll` is for Windows. On Linux it's called `mbstring.so`

Comment: I agree with what you are saying. Question is why would a windows error show in ubuntu and how can I install the mbstring.so library?

Comment: sir @jaahvicky I have the same problem.Are you have the key?please share if.

Answer (score 12):

In php.ini
search "extension_dir" : 
uncomment for the platform 
(in my case it is on Windows:)

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir = "ext"
```

Answer (score 8):

I was running into the same PHP warnings when trying to run it from the command line. This was on a Homestead Vagrant Ubuntu box, where i was getting:

```
 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'/usr/lib/php/20160303/php_mbstring.dll' - 
/usr/lib/php/20160303/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object file: No 
such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'/usr/lib/php/20160303/php_exif.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/php_exif.dll: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

What I didn't realize is that it uses a php.ini in a separate /cli/ directory (E.g. /etc/php/7.X/cli/php.ini) when you're running php on the command line or using a CLI that uses PHP

Based on the paths in your question, look for /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini and you should comment out the mbstring module (assuming Linux):

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_mbstring.dll ; commented out
```

If this doesn't solve the issue for you, try running:

```
php -i | grep -i "Loaded Configuration File"
```

This pointed me at the correct php.ini file:

```
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue regarding PHP extension, you need to enable mbstring extension in php.ini file.

> File Path: /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini

Line no around 903.

There will be

> ;extension=php_mbstring.dll

It should be

> extension=php_mbstring.dll

Comment: in modern PHP (tested with 8.2.0) all extension are listed in `php.ini` in a platform-independent manner like `extension=mbstring` or `extension=openssl`, and the engine is smart enough to find them if the location is specified (like `extension_dir = "ext"` for Windows or `extension_dir = "./"` for Linux)

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. But in my case, the problem was the because of open server. After I run the open server, everything is going well!